# Get windows credentials in Angular 6 MVC 5 App

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication

I'm relatively new to Angular. I have an MVC 5 app with Angular 6 front-end. I have enabled Windows authentication in MVC (with Web.config). The authentication works fine, but my question is how do I display username and such details in my Angular view?

`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` works in an MVC view, but I am not sure how to get it in an Angular view.

Any code example would be a great help! Thanks.